# Hosting GPT-3 on cloud server in KSA

Tags: nlp, openai-api, chatgpt-api, gpt-3, large-language-model

What is the alternative of LLM models that can be hosted on a cloud server on Saudi Arabia. These LLMs should be very good on supporting Arabic

Comment: I am running into the same issue myself.
I am cycling through quite a few LLMs that say they support Arabic (mostly multilingual) . Thus far I have no success.